# Scala Lagom development mode & Docker

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, jwt, lagom

we have a Scala service built on top of Lagom. We use JWT to authenticate the connections when deployed.

Locally we developers use `sbt runAll` to run our service. This works fine and it circumvents the JWT authentication (I assume because of Lagom's development mode when running `runAll`).

However, we would like to run unit tests locally in Docker containers (some other services mocked, but with a real mysql and imported test data). Inside the docker containers, the JWT authentication is used (presumably because it's not running in development mode). This makes it a lot more difficult to run the tests.

Is there a way to enable development mode also when deploying through docker (preferably through an env variable, so that we can enable that only on the local instances and disable dev mode on the deployed cluster)?

Many thanks,
Volker

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean by JWT authentication? Lagom doesn't provide any JWT authentication features out of the box. Play, which Lagom sits on top of, does provide JWT based season management, but this isn't exposed to through the Lagom API, and also isn't disabled in dev mode.

So likely whatever these JWT features are, they are provided by a third party library, or your own app has provided them.

Comment: We're using `org.pac4j.lagom.jwt.JwtAuthenticatorHelper`. We have a `trait SecurityModule extends LagomConfigComponent` that uses pac4j to implement a number of different `HeaderClient`s. We then have a `HeaderFilter` that filters out the requests if dev mode is not set (`val mode = Play.maybeApplication.map(_.mode).getOrElse(Dev); if (mode == Prod) ...`). The question is how I can launch Play in Dev mode while running inside the Docker container.

Comment: If you can check for dev mode, you can check for an env variable being set from docker as well. No need for dev mode.